# How can I create payment plans using Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to sell a $12,000 item and allow people to pay in 3 payments of $4,000.

Stripe only allows me to charge $4,000 per month with no expiration on the payments.

Is there simple "off the shelf" software I could use to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this with Stripe would be to count the number of payments for the customer, and once they've reached the number of required payments, you'd delete their subscription. You could use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to get notifications from Stripe each time a customer makes a payment.